# Is there a block chain bootstrap for Litecoin?

Tags: blockchain, litecoin, bootstrap.dat

For Bitcoin, various people distribute a `bootstrap.dat` file which contains a snapshot of the blockchain.  A new Bitcoin user can download this file and verify it with their client, which is often more efficient than downloading the entire chain from the peer-to-peer network.

Does something similar exist for Litecoin?

Comment: Why aren't there examples out there in which one can use to create their own blockchain.dat file?

Comment: Bootstrap.dat I mean

Answer (score 2):

The site below has good information, including guides for different operating systems:

[litecoin.info/Bootstrap.dat](https://litecoin.info/Bootstrap.dat)

Comment: Don't bother using the torrent files... NO ONE is seeding. I've waited weeks for the torrent download to finish, should have just suffered through the wallet update. Guess greed motivated the lack of seeding.

Comment: @user24750 I see 2 seeds in the torrent. It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

http://blockchain.litecoin.net

There may be a warning on the site but what you should do is put the blk0001.dat file in the Litecoin data folder (~/.litecoin by default on gnu/linux) then when you run litecoind or litecoin-qt for the first time, include the -reindex option on the command line.